# Html button doesn't click

Tags: php, html, button, click

I would like to know how I could fix this issue. My html button doesn't click at all.

I believe it must be due to incorrect div setting or a background or something issue.

I am wondering, what setting should I can so the "sign the petition" here becomes clickable
http://188.166.54.129/signit.php
thank you

Edit: I just notice the radio is not clickable either.
You can't select the no option in the form. I believe both issue must be linked?

I can't put the input radio in the overflow code option, but it is available on the web server if needed

```html
<section class="features-extended section">
  <div class="features-extended-inner section-inner">
    <div class="features-extended-wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
          <h3 class="mt-0 mb-16">
            <center>Sign the petition here</center>
          </h3>
          <form method="post" action="signit">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label>Full name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label>Comment</label>
              <input type="text" name="comment">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label>Residency / Address</label>
              <input type="text" name="region">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label for="canada">Do you currently live in Canada? </label>
              <p>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <button type="submit" name="signit">Sign the petition</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It is clickable. I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: (You might want to try using the element selector in your browser's developer tools and see where a click on the button actually lands).

Comment: "Edit: I just notice the radio is not clickable either. You can't select the no option in the form. I believe both issue must be linked?" - Yes, they are, but the problem isn't with the code you shared in the question. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Quentin my goal would be to implement the form in the same visual as the whole website but if it becomes too complicated I could just make a form without visual that is clickable and send back to the visual after they have signed. What do you think?

Not sure how to use browser developer tool and click on the button. I am just learning by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats due to footer `.site-footer` styling remove `position:relative` from it and it will work

Comment: There is no element with `site-footer` in the question.

Comment: @Quentin see the code before commenting don't write non sense comment , see the site which op attached

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Also see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) which says "Answer well-asked questions"

Comment: I tried to upvote but my user is to recent, I think